# Why is false sharing an issue if the variable being modified by a thread is marked as volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I've been looking at the Martin Thompson article. Which is an explanation of false sharing.

http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/false-sharing.html

```
    public final class FalseSharing
    implements Runnable
    {
        public final static int NUM_THREADS = 4; // change
        public final static long ITERATIONS = 500L * 1000L * 1000L;
        private final int arrayIndex;

        private static VolatileLong[] longs = new VolatileLong[NUM_THREADS];


        static
        {    
            for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++)
            {
                longs[i] = new VolatileLong();
            }
        }

        public FalseSharing(final int arrayIndex)
        {
            this.arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            final long start = System.nanoTime();
            runTest();
            System.out.println("duration = " + (System.nanoTime() -start));
        }

        private static void runTest() throws InterruptedException
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];

            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new FalseSharing(i));
            }

            for (Thread t : threads)
            {
                t.start();
            }

            for (Thread t : threads)
            {
                t.join();
            }
        }

        public void run()
        {
            long i = ITERATIONS + 1;
            while (0 != --i)
            {
                longs[arrayIndex].value = i;
            }
        }

        public final static class VolatileLong
        {
            public volatile long value = 0L;
            public long p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6; // comment out
        }
    }
```

The example demonstrates the slow down experienced by multiple threads invalidating the cache line of each other even though there each only updating one variable exclusively.

> BlockqFigure 1. above illustrates the issue of false sharing.  A thread running on core 1 wants to update variable X while a thread on core 2 wants to update variable Y.  Unfortunately these two hot variables reside in the same cache line.  Each thread will race for ownership of the cache line so they can update it.  If core 1 gets ownership then the cache sub-system will need to invalidate the corresponding cache line for core 2.  When Core 2 gets ownership and performs its update, then core 1 will be told to invalidate its copy of the cache line.  This will ping pong back and forth via the L3 cache greatly impacting performance.  The issue would be further exacerbated if competing cores are on different sockets and additionally have to cross the socket interconnect.

My question is the following. If all the variables being updated are volatile, why does this padding cause a performance increase? My understanding is that a volatile variable always writes and reads through to main memory. Therefore I'd assume that every write and read to any variable in this example will result in a flush of the current cores cache line.

So according to my understanding. If thread one invalidates thread two's cacheline, this will not become apparant to thread two until it goes to read a value from its own cache line. The value it's reading is a volatile value so this effectively renders the cache dirty anyway resulting in a read from main memory.

Where have I gone wrong in my understanding?

Thanks

Comment: `volatile` is a hint to the compiler, letting it know that a value may change, even if it doesn't appear so locally. While this causes a reload, it can be read from cache.

Comment: @JohnnyCage That isnonsense. Volatile is an important keyword for multi-threading (not a "hint" to the compiler), just like the synchronized keyword and the [Java Memory Model specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) describes its operation. How the memory model is implemented depends on the JVM, the CPU and memory architecture, etc. and the real implementation probably has more impact on this than the JMM.

Comment: Your assumption that it forces a synchronous memory read/write is incorrect. It inserts [memory barriers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt), but the CPU is allowed to optimize that as long as it maintains consistency.

Comment: Memory barriers are what force the memory read/write synchronization @Ben.  Reading from a volatile crosses a read memory barrier the same way that entering a `synchronization` block does.  `synchronization` blocks also provide mutex locking of course but the memory barriers are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If all the variables being updated are volatile, why does this padding cause a performance increase?

So there are two things going on here:

1. We are dealing with an array of `VolatileLong` objects with each thread working on their own `VolatileLong`. (See `private final int arrayIndex`).
2. Each of the `VolatileLong` object has a single `volatile` field.

The `volatile` access means that the threads have to both invalidate the [cache "line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) that holds their `volatile long value` and they need to lock that cache line to update it.  As the article states, a cache line is typically ~64 bytes or so.

The article is saying that by adding padding to the `VolatileLong` object, it moves the object that each of the threads is locking into *different* cache lines.  So even though the different threads are still crossing memory barriers as they assign their `volatile long value`, they are in a different cache line an so won't cause excessive L2 cache bandwidth.

In summary, the performance increase happens because even though the threads are still locking their cache line to update the `volatile` field, these locks are now on different memory blocks and so they are not clashing with the other threads' locks and causing cache invalidations.

Comment: +1 Loved your explanation ! But, I don't have a damn idea about cache lines (in hardware level) and L2..L(N) cache. Can you please help me with some link to understand these terms at hardware/software level?

Comment: I just did a search for: cpu cache line.  The wikipedia page looks like a good place to start @VishalK:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache